# How to set up a while loop using a variable given to keep repeating a word, and adding them to an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, bluej

I am having trouble using the while loop and I don't know what the problem is.
I am using BlueJ and the questions says to create an ArrayList of String called words

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter words...enter stop to finish, I will sort them alphabetically");
```

I wrote this code but I am not sure of it, keep in mind I should use a while loop using the variable and add it to the ArrayList.

```
boolean done = false;
while ( done = false ){ 
String word = keys.next();
if(word.equals("stop")){
done = true;
}
```

Comment: `while ( String s : words){ }` does not make sense, you should put a condition in there or use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: that's the thing I want to use a for loop but the question insists using a while loop @luk2302

Comment: `for (init; cond; step) { body; }` can be re-written to `init; while (true) { if(!cond) break; body; step; }` - not pretty and a bad idea but works. And a `for (... : ...)` is just another more elegant `for` loop but can be changed to a normal for loop.

Comment: I used another way to work on it but I am not sure of the code @luk2302

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and if it meets your requirement

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            String inputString = keys.next();
            words.add(inputString);
            if (inputString.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your condition: `while ( done = false )` you need to put `==` 2 equal sign to check for value but you are assigning false value each time to done.

I tried to use `do-while` loop to have one iteration before checking the condition.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

boolean done = false;
do {
    String word = input.next();
    words.add(word);
    if("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
        done = true;
    }
}while(!done);
System.out.println(words);
```